# Graphical model inference package on Lua/Torch

Tags: machine-learning, lua, torch

I am trying to find a package on Lua/Torch for graphical model inference.  The cheatsheet mentioned two:

1. OpenGM: https://github.com/clementfarabet/lua---opengm
2. GM: https://github.com/clementfarabet/gm

The former looks more fledged, but when I ran "luarocks install opengm", it returned an error:

Error: No results matching query were found.

The latter is prototypical and cannot perform exact inference on a linear chain.

Could anybody recommend a package for graphical model inference on Lua?

Thanks.